# mysql push index into memory

Tags: mysql, memory, indexing

I use MySQL (MyISA). Table with over 8M rows. Primary index on 'id'.

My application show:

```
first run: 55 req/sec, 
second run: ~120 req/sec, 
third run: ~1200 req/sec, 
fourth run: ~4500 req/sec, 
fifth run: ~9999 req/sec
```

After restart mysql-server again the same.
How placing ALL index at once in memory after start database server?

In my.cnf

```
key_buffer_size=2000M
```

**Code sample:**

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
cursor = connection.cursor()
for x in xrange(1, 10000):
    id = random.randint(10, 100000) # random first 10000 records for cache
    cursor.execute("""SELECT num, manufacturer_id
                   FROM product WHERE id=%s LIMIT 1""", [id])
    cursor.fetchone()    

td = datetime.datetime.now() - now
sec = td.seconds + td.days * 24 * 3600
print "%.2f operation/sec" % (float(x) / float(sec))
```

Comment: See http://openquery.com/blog/cache-preloading-mysqld-startup

Answer (score 0):

I think two caches are at work here. One is the index cache and that can be preloaded with [LOAD INDEX INTO CACHE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-preloading.html)

The other is the [query cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-cache.html) and I think that in your case this is where the most performance is gained. AFAIK that can't be preloaded with any mysql command.

What you could do is to replace the last N queries that run before the restart. Those queries would then poplate the cache. Or keep a file of some realistic queries to run at start up.

Comment: If you want to see "QUERY-CACHE-independent" performance, one may want to add the `/*! SQL_NO_CACHE */` hint on the query. That way you'll see if index caching, page pre-fetching or table cache are actually prevalent there.